# Global notification of moderator elections have the wrong URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, stack-exchange-button

From my stomping grounds at [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/), I checked out the [new global notification system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/).  (I'm really happy about the change, by the way.  It's so much better than Big Slidy Orange.)  At any rate I see there's a moderator election on the Mathematics site:

[image: Global notification on the BH.SE site]

But this is what I got:

[image: Got the wrong URL.]

The URL went to: `https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election` and not `http://math.stackexchange.com/election`.

Comment: Guess who forgot to make a link absolute?  Fixing now.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm guessing Jeff. ;-)

Comment: Well played, blaming Jeff. But -1 for dishonoring the memory of Slidy.

Comment: I saw *"Does the Bible mention unicorns?"* as a question title in your screenshot and just assumed that you doctored it for [the purposes of posting on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/153008). But much to my surprise, [this is actually a real question on BH](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/106/does-the-bible-mention-unicorns)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fixed now, let me know if you find any more busted links; as with all new features there were probably a few oversights.

Comment: FYI: all the non-moderator-election notifications in my box had good links.  Thanks for fixing this (minor) bug so quickly.

Comment: comment comment comment